# Gradle uses locally stored dependencies or allways download content from internet?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When importing a eclipse project to gradle I see this advice:

> The Gradle project needs network connectivity to download
>   dependencies.

My project is a generator that auto-compiles APK files. This means that each time one APK is compiled, gradle will download `android-support-v4.jar` and `GooglePLayServices7.8.0` dependencies.

Will Gradle use downloaded versions available in the sdk folder?

Answer (score 0):

Gradle donwload one time dependencies and cache them after. First time, it needs network connectivity depends if your dependencies are remote or local.

Comment: where did you find that? i can't find it in official documentation

Answer (score 0):

Gradle can import offline JAR libraries to your project, other than that it downloads the dependencies from the internet unless you change its settings to "Work Offline".

Comment: it will download allways it compiles a project? or it will use locally previous download items?

Comment: it will download for the first time you build your project then it will use a cached version of your dependencies, but you have to set it to "Work Offline" in the Gradle settings in Android Studio.

Comment: file -> settings -> in the search box write the word "offline work" -> it will appear on the right, please accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: if i dont use android studio... because this will be used with command line compile commands, where can i activate offline work?